# can I import all flow types at once?

Tags: flowtype, typechecking

Let's suppose I have this:

```
import type { Collection } from './x.types.js';
import type { Collection } from './y.types.js';
```

I would like to import both like this:

```
import type * as XTypes from './x.types.js';
import type * as YTypes from './y.types.js';
```

because in my code I will have a namespace, I can easily recognise where they are coming from and I will not have any declaration's conflict.

```
const something = (collection: Xtypes.collection) => {}
const something2 = (collection: Ytypes.collection) => {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can import everything from the module and access the types like you would any exports from the module:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFC4QB2q8yAXJlTAHQCiANlhBYGMADxkAJsABuZAHxwAvHFFTpcgCpZmogPRq5QA))

```
import * as React from 'react'
const a: React.Element<'div'> = <div>Test</div>
```

I don't think an `import type * as ReactTypes` syntax exists at the moment. If you use the above syntax, I hope you're using tree shaking or you're already using that module somewhere else. It would be a shame to bloat your deployed code just to use this shorthand import.

Comment: Yeah, that's just an example